# Network.enable is not working on devTools

Tags: java, selenium

[image]

```java
ChromeDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
DevTools devTool = driver.getDevTools();
devTool.createSession();
devTool.send(Network.enable(Optional.empty(), Optional.empty(),Optional.empty()));
```

In the line `devTool.send(Network.enable(Optional.empty(), Optional.empty(),Optional.empty()));` I am getting the error as shown in the screenshot above.

The error is as follows:

> ×The method enable(Optional, Optional, Optional) in the type Network is not applicable for the arguments (Optional, Optional, Optional)
> try to get Network Request and Response

Answer (score 0):

Even I got the same error but I continued adding a listener and the error was gone

`enter code here`

```
    DevTools devTools = driver.getDevTools();
    devTools.createSession();
    
    devTools.send(Network.enable(
            Optional.empty(),
            Optional.empty(),
                Optional.empty()));
    
    //devTools.send(Network.enable(null,null,null));
    devTools.addListener(Network.requestWillBeSent(), request -> {System.out.println("Reuest URL:" +request.getRequest().getUrl());
    System.out.println("Request Method: "+request.getRequest().getMethod());});
    
    
    driver.get("https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75028157/network-enable-is-not-working-on-devtools");
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).